# Add Session data to ListBox

Tags: asp.net, session, listbox, session-variables

I didn't write all code. It just a part of sessions which has already data inside. I just want to get all data from sessiosn by which Session["sepet"] to add Listbox but I couldn't do that. There is no any error message. Actually the code purpose is, I wanted to add all data to Listbox after that I want to send all data what include the Listbox to SQL Database. I don't know is there any different way to do.

```
 private void SepetGetir1()
{
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();
    if (Session["sepet"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = (DataTable)Session["sepet"];
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            lst.Add(r["ID"].ToString());
            lst.Add(r["productName"].ToString());
        }
        ListBox1.DataSource = lst;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the data table to the ListBox, and specify which field is used for `Text` and wihch one is used for `Value`:

```
DataTable dt = Session["sepet"] as DataTable;
ListBox1.DataSource = dt;
ListBox1.DataTextField = "productname";
ListBox1.DataValueField = "ID";
ListBox1.DataBind();
```